# Is it possible to use the PayPal REST APIs to charge a card client side?

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I'm currently working on an iOS app where I would like to control the user experience of the entire checkout process when the user is paying directly by credit card. The PayPal iOS SDK doesn't quite fit my use case as it has a baked in ViewController that must be displayed to complete the payment.

The PayPal REST API's appear to allow me to charge a user's card directly but would require my secret key in the process implying it should only be used for some server side flow.

The PayPalPaymentViewController does have an option to take credit card payments directly from the user so I wonder if these services being used to accomplish this are publicly available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd be curious as to why the provided view controller is inadequate. The goal is to provide a minimal interface in which to accept credit cards.

But, yes, these services are [publicly available](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest-payments-overview/). A limited set of functionality (e.g. sale transaction) is possible by omitting the OAuth2 secret.

However, you will still want to [verify the transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/) on your own server in order to avoid being spoofed by a malicious user.

Comment: Hi Tom, It's not inadequate by any means! I'm running an A/B test in the checkout process to compare checkout conversion with an inline credit card form vs the PayPalPaymentViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to replace the paypal ViewController with anything else, you might run into lots of legal trouble. For example, here in germany, the size and text of the "purchase" button is regulated by law. Paypal's Lawyers have checked the german version of the ViewController for correctness. If anyone, in germany, uses your app, and makes purchases with a different UI, chances are very high that a) the transaction is void and b) german authorities will prosecute you for fraud. Don't risk that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll definitely take that into account! Lets assume though that I know of any edges cases in the country or countries I would like to operate -- in such a situation do I have any options?